# Toggle sort order with a command button

Tags: sorting, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I'm using

```
DoCmd.SetOrderBy
```

for sorting a form by a specific field. But right now it sorts ascending or descending if I use `DESC` keyword. How can I do a check to see what sorting is active and do the opposite? If that field is ordered ascending and I click the button, the order become descending and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sam suggested, check the value of the `Me.OrderBy` property to decide whether you want ascending or descending for the new sort order.

The following code sample assumes you want an ascending sort if there is no current sort (i.e. `Me.OrderBy` is an empty string).

Otherwise check whether `Me.OrderBy` is `Like "* DESC"`.  Note, if the current sort order is ascending, don't assume `ASC` will be present in `Me.OrderBy`.  And don't assume the column name piece of `Me.OrderBy` will be present as `[FORM].[COLUMN]`.

```vb
Dim strOrderBy As String
Dim strDirection As String

strOrderBy = Me.OrderBy
If Len(strOrderBy) = 0 Then
    strDirection = "ASC"
Else
    If strOrderBy Like "* DESC" Then
        strDirection = "ASC"
    Else
        strDirection = "DESC"
    End If ' Like 
End If ' Len(strOrderBy)
DoCmd.SetOrderBy "[YourColumnName] " & strDirection
```

Comment: If I try to run this code it triggers an Invalid use of Me keyword error

Comment: That code must be in the form's module.  I thought your form includes a command button, and you want to toggle the sort when the button is clicked.  If so, put that code in the button's click event procedure.  Did you have something else in mind?

Comment: Yes, it is that I have in mind. If I put that code in button's click event procedure it outputs that error, if I put that in the form's module I can't figure out how to make it functioning, sorry

Comment: Ponzaro, send us the code you have so far for the button that changes the order

Comment: The button's click event procedure should be included in the form's code module.  It sounds like your button click procedure is in a different code module.

Comment: @HansUp Ok, I was doing it wrong, your code works flawlessly, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current sort order by doing in the form code

```
debug.print me.orderby
```

It will come out something like

```
[FORM].[COLUMN] Desc
```

So then do an if statement

```
if me.orderby = [FORM].[COLUMN] Desc then 
    docmd.setorderby "[COLUMN] ASC"
else
    docmd.setorderby "[COLUMN] Desc"
end if
```

Try that out. Changing the FORM and COLUMN to match yours of course

Comment: I think I'm missing something. In the design view of the form, i clicked on view code and put the debug.print there, but it doesn't output anything on the form

Comment: It won't output on the form. But instead in the immediate bar in vba. It is like a message box apart from it does not stop any code running or pop up. In access press ctrl+g and it will bring you straight to it

Comment: Well, If I enter that code, open the form and press ctrl+g it doesn't output anything anyway.

Comment: Add sam's `debug.print me.orderby` VBA code to the on-click event of your command button. In the VBA code editor, make sure the immediate window is showing at the bottom (Ctrl + G or View > Immediate Window). Go back to your form and switch it back to Form View and then click your command button. If you go back to the code editor (Alt + F11) you should see what Sam's describing output in the immediate window.

Comment: If you are having trouble put it in a msgbox and have it like @Matt Hall says to be a on-click event. That way every time you click it it will show up a message box showing the current orderby